# Wordpress Media Library Attachment Details

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

How to add a custom button/link in between "Edit Image" and "Delete Permanently" ?

[image: attachment detail on right side of Media library tab (when image/media selected)]

if that not possible as above, is it possible to add custom button/link in "Attachment Details" popup aside "Edit Image" Button?

[image: Media >Library>click on any media]

is there any filter or hooks in wordpress to do it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add custom link/button, you have control over the template in `wp-includes/media-template.php` see [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media-template.php#L567)